# org.w3c.dom.Node.setNodeValue() not encoding certain special characters

Tags: java, xml, encoding, xmlnode

Using Java, I set the value of a `<value>` attribute in an xml file to be

`String val = "~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\\:\";'<>?,./;"`

When I tried to use the api with input

`org.w3c.dom.Node.setNodeValue(val)`

and take a look at the xml, I see that the value attribute in the resulting xml looks this way-

`<Value>~!@#$%^&amp;*()_+-={}|[]\:";'&lt;>?,./</Value>`

I'm trying to figure out why this third party API is encoding only `<` and `&`, but not `>`, `'` or `"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply because it doesn't *need* to escape `>`, `'` or `"`.

The quotes would only need to be encoded in an attribute which was opened with the same kind of quote (so `foo="single'quote"` or `bar='double"quote'` is fine) and the closing angle bracket doesn't need to be encoded either, as it doesn't have any meaning when you're not potentially closing the element.

It would be entirely valid for it to encode them anyway - but *not* doing so is valid too.

Comment: But what if these characters are used as part of html tags? What if the value attribute contains these special characters? Especially `>`? Can't that be considered as the closing of an html tag?

Comment: I'm talking about a situation where we are reading from xml and writing into html.

Comment: @AlwaysALearner: You shouldn't expect an *XML* library to care about what *HTML* wants. But frankly I'd expect HTML to be okay with those too. You can't close an element half way through an attribute, can you? I know browsers are often lenient with their parsing, but I would *expect* valid XML to be valid HTML in this case.

Comment: @AlwaysALearner if the "<" is part of a tag then you shouldn't be writing it using setNodeValue(). Using that method implies that the characters are part of the text content, not part of the markup.

Comment: So, does that mean that `Node.setTextContent()` the right approach?

Comment: @AlwaysALearner: I'd expect that to behave the same way, to be honest. (I'd have to check the API to be sure though.)